# Extending a java class with generics dynamically

Tags: java, generics, aspectj, javassist

is possible to use aspectj or javassist for extending a class with a generic class? for example i have a class with:

```
@someAnnotation(GenerictTypeParameter.class)
public aClass{
  ...
}
```

so the idea is to search all classes with @someAnnotation and then extending them  with another class and get this:

```
public aClass extends anotherClass<GenericTypeParameter>{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Given that you have to add the annotation and parameter to the class anyway, what would this give you vs explicitly extending in the regular way?

Comment: i'm curious about this, and i want to know if is possible, maybe can be helpful for understand what you can do with these tecnologies, maybe it will be helpful to decide what class to extend depending of what annotations you add and the necessity of add generics. For example if `@someAnnotation` is present extend to a class but if also `@someAnotheAnnotation` is present then extend to another class, maybe also for decoupling of the extended class.

Comment: @DiegoFernandoMurilloValenci please keep in mind that generics do not exist on the bytecode level, only in the source. Therefore using **javaassist** makes no sense and it does not support generics for this reason. **aspectj** could do something here, providing you use 'source code' aspect weaving rather than bytecode or loader weaving strategies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy), if you are willing to use another code generation library. With Byte Buddy, you can:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(TypeDescription.Generic.Builder
              .parameterizedType(AnotherClass.class, GenericTypeParameter.class)
              .build())
  .make();
```

You can simply resolve the relevant type from the annotation. Byte Buddy also allows you to redefine existing types if this is what you are trying to achieve.